# Can't set sink description to string with spaces

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm trying to create a null sink and I want to set a description so that it can be recognized easily. I'm able to do it with a name without spaces but if I try to add spaces, the sink isn't created.

This what I've tried :

`

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=my-sink sink_properties=device.description="My sink"
`

`pacmd 'load-module module-null-sink sink_name=my-sink sink_properties=device.description="My sink" '
`

`pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=my-sink sink_properties=device.description='"My sink"'
`
```

And all these commands return 0, like it was a success, but if I run `pactl list short modules` the sink is not created.

I also tried updating the sink after it was created using

```
pacmd update-sink-proplist my-sink device.description='"My sink"`
```

but the command returns also 0 and don't change anything

And one more thing : I want to do it via command line, and without setting the sink in config files.

I'd be glad if someone could help.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/615 pacmd update-sink-proplist some_sink device.description="\"A description for some_sink.\"" Or have you already solved this issue otherwise?